# ncurses, print and contemporary acquire strings

Tags: c, concurrency, while-loop, screen, ncurses

A program written in C uses `ncurses`. A `while` cycle is used to continuously check if a new message is arrived in a queue: if it is, the message is printed on screen and then removed from the queue:

```
while (condition)
{
if (queue_not_empty)
{
printw(element_from_queue);
refresh();
remove(element_from_queue);
}
}
```

At the same time, however, the program should be able to acquire an input string from the user and then store it in the array `char message[100]` through a `scanw`.
But if I put

```
while (condition)
{
if (queue_not_empty)
{
printw(element_from_queue);
refresh();
remove(element_from_queue);
}
scanw(message);
}
```

the cycle will stop until the user doesn't type a string and the program will print the new messages of the queue only **after** a user input. It should not be like this! The queue messages could arrive at any time and should be printed; the user messages could arrive at any time and should be stored into the array.

I would like to avoid the creation of another thread, because `ncurses` becomes weird with multiple threads. Anyway, I would need two "contemporary" `while` cycles, one for printing the messages and one for reading the user input.

May there be a solution?

In other words: is it possible with `ncurses` to print some output and to get some **multiple characters** input from the user in the same screen, **in the same thread**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ncurses provides functions for reading a *single* character with a [timeout](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-timeout_wtimeout) (or even [no delay](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-nodelay) at all).  Those are not useful with [`scanw`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_scanw.3x.html) (which always blocks, waiting for *several* characters):

- when using a timeout, [`getch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h2-RETURN-VALUE) returns `ERR` rather than a character when the timeout expires.
- [`scanw`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_scanw.3x.html) may use `getch` internally, but has no way to continue when `getch` returns `ERR`.

Rather than *block*, you can *poll* for input.  If no character is available within a given time interval, your program gives up (for the moment), and does something more useful than waiting for characters.
Applications that poll for input can be written to accept characters one at a time, adding them to a buffer until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and *then* run **[`sscanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)** on the completed text.

The regular C `sscanf` is used (which reads from a *string*) rather than reading directly from the *screen* with `scanw`.

Comment: thank you, but how can I *poll* for input and which functions should be used?

Comment: The links point to `timeout` and `nodelay` (the suggested functions to use).